# all other variables being constant, is it true that sql servers in general run faster than mysql databases?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, performance

All other variables being constant, which is faster at inserting / deleting / modifying / anddoing lookups: sql server or mysql (you can choose any engine which is the fastest)

(leave the other databases out of the discussion)

We will not compare propriety functions that either sql server has only or mysql server has only.

For example, like say I have 8 million entries in a table in sql server and the same entries in the same table in mysql server.

Will finding for the 7997777th row be faster in sql server or mysql?

Another example, say I do an insert into a table in sql server vs the same insert in the same table in mysql?

Answer (score 3):

How fast either works in this case is going to be much more a factor of your I/O subsystem than which platform you use - but it can also depend slightly on what your data looks like and whether you really want to ignore any proprietary methods one platform or the other has for dealing more effectively with that much data (e.g. in SQL Server I would likely opt for BULK INSERT, SQLBulkCopy, etc).

Of course, you could always try it.

Comment: explain why the question is bad.

Answer (score 1):

In general the ISAM type engines will appear faster in novice comparisons. And since SQL Server uses an engine which is much more closer to the InnoDB engine (and hence appears slower than default ISAM engine), is often cited that MySQL is faster. The critical factor is *concurrency*: the ISAM type engines are faster *under single user workloads* and fall apart as soon as concurrent workloads are being tested (see [MyISAM versus InnoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20148/myisam-versus-innodb)). there are other factors too, like warm up time not being considered (since InnoDB like engines need to warm up the buffer pool, but ISAM ones work reasonably fast on cold caches).

When comparing SQL Server with InnoDB the numbers will vary a lo from workload to workload, but SQL Server tends to scale better on higher end systems (> 16 CPUs). there are many SQL Server published TPC-C, [TPC-E](http://www.tpc.org/tpce/results/tpce_perf_results.asp) and [TPC-H](http://www.tpc.org/tpch/results/tpch_perf_results.asp) benchmarks and MySQL is nowhere featured in any (except for [Kickfire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kickfire), which is a special case).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on many factors. For example mysql has different storage engines with different speeds and performances. But according to your needs u can perform a benchmark to see which one suit best.